# Concatenate two tensors with different shapes in Keras

Tags: keras

In the following diagram, I have two different tensors: tensor1 and tensor2.

How do I merge (concatenate) these two tensors such that input to LSTM is now:
(tensor1[0], tensor1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZHf3.jpg), concatenate(tensor1[2], tensor2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZHf3.jpg))) ??

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to concatenate them as they are. You have to manipulate them. So, how do you intend to fill the 6 timesteps that are inexistent in tensor 2? Copy tensor 2 six times? As if you had a constant sequence of 6 steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to concatenate them.

You need to manipulate, transform them somehow. 
The most logical thing I can think of is repeating tensor 2 six times to fill the timesteps that it doesn't have.

If this is ok (transforming tensor 2 into a sequence of 6 constant steps), the solution is:

```
tensor2Repeated = RepeatVector(6)(tensor2)
tensor = Concatenate()([tensor1,tensor2Repeated])
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, is Concatenate() from numpy, tf.concat or keras layer?

Comment: `Concatenate` is either from https://keras.io/layers/merge/ or https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Concatenate

Comment: Keras layer: `keras.layers.Concatenate`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to reduce redundancy? You only have to replicate the second tensor 3 times to produce the same amount of information as the first tensor, then you simply reshape. To concatenate an arbitrary number of tensors, simply calculate the size of each minus the last axis (multiply all the axes before last to get size), find the largest tensor m, then upsample or repeat each tensor x by ceiling(m.size / x.size). Then you simply reshape each with the same axes as m except for the last axis, which you either calculate or let your framework calculate implicitly with -1.

```
tensor2Repeated = RepeatVector(3)(tensor2)
tensor2Reshaped = reshape(tensor2Repeated, (32, 6, 1))
tensor = Concatenate()([tensor1,tensor2Reshaped])
```